# Monitor folder on windows network from unix server using camel file component

Tags: java, windows, unix, apache-camel

How doe we monitor a folder in Windows network from unix server using camel file component?

When I run my program from Windows it works fine but when I deploy my jar on unix server it doesnt read the windows filepath.

Comment: What Windows filepath, and how are you trying to read it? Is this a *How do I mount a smb share on Unix question?*

Comment: I'm trying to read the windows path from unix using camel file component eg:- from("file:\\\\10.22.34.56\\TestFolder\\?move=archive/${file:name}.${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}").bean(Test.class,"postFileWatcher()");

Comment: You almost certainly need to mount the Windows path first. What version of "Unix" are you using? `uname -a`

Comment: uname -a
SunOS s01srmsapp3a 5.10 Generic_150400-09 sun4v sparc sun4v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this [Oracle blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/timthomas/entry/enabling_and_configuring_samba_as) post

> Sun ships SAMBA with Solaris 9 & Solaris 10 and it is supported as part of the Operating System.

[First](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/solaris-opensolaris-mount-windows-shared-cifs/), you need to enable the ([Samba](http://www.samba.org/)) Client Service

```
svcadm enable network/smb/client
```

Then create a mount-point (e.g. "/testFolder"),

```
mkdir /testFolder
mount -F smbfs //10.22.34.56/TestFolder /testFolder
```

Then you should be able to use camel to monitor "/testFolder" on your Unix server (which will actually map to the folder on your Windows share).

You should also be able to view available share names on your server (like so)

```
smbutil view //10.22.34.56
```